# Replace the constraint using ==> by a linear formulation

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, linearization, scheduling, logical-constraints

I would like to know how to express the continuity constraint without using a decision variable in the conditional form. My challenge is to stay with **a linear formulation**.
I will start to explain my model :
We would like to determine the optimal starting and finishing date of the project while respecting the human resource capacity available to execute the project.

One of the assumptions is that **the project could not be interrupted during its executing period,** means once it starts it should be executed continually. Thus, we would like to express this constraint using a linear formulation :

**subject to continuityConstraint {j in P, t in T: t >= 2}:
t <= Fin[j]  ==>  Act[j,t] >= Act[j,t-1];**

We are not with a linear model anymore

**Sets :**

set P:= {1..n}; #set of projects

set RType:={"Project manager", "Technical Expert", "Financial Analyst", "Estimator", "Contractual manager"}; #set of human resources

set T:= {1..l}; #set of terms

set S:= {"SP", "MP", "LP", "XLP"};#set of project sizes : small, medium, large and major

set PS within {P,S}; # Set of project-size combinations

**Parameters :**

param ES{j in P}; # Earliest starting of the project

param LF{j in P}; # Latest finishing of the project

param Duration{j in P};# duration of project j

param RDemand{s in S, r in RType}; # total number of required resource type r to be allocated to project j on any term within its duration

param Av{r in RType, t in T}>=0; #avaialibility of each human resource type r at the period t

**Deicision variables :**

var Act{j in P, t in T} binary; #=1 if the project j is executing durint period t and 0 otherwise

var FinMax {j in P} integer;

var Debut{j in P} integer; # starting date of the project j

var Fin{j in P} integer; # Finishing date of the project j

var Y{j in P, r in RType, t in T} integer;# number of human resource type r allocated to project j at period t

**Constraints :**

subject to DurationConstraint {j in P}:

sum{t in T} Act[j, t] = Duration[j];

subject to AffectConstraint {r in RType, t in T}:

sum {j in P, (j,s) in PS} RDemand[s,r]*Act[j,t]<= Av[r,t];

subject to DemandConstraint {j in P, (j,s) in PS, (j, m) in PM, r in RType,t in T}:

Y[j, r, t] =RDemand[s,m,r]*Act[j,t];

subject to Max_Constraint{j in P, t in T}:

t * Act[j, t] <= FinMax[j];

subject to Define_Fin{j in P}:

Fin[j] = FinMax[j];

subject to ActConstraint {j in P}:

(Fin[j]-Debut[j]) =(sum{t in T} Act[j,t])-1;

subject to FinishConstraint {j in P, t in T: t > LF[j]}:

Act[j,t]=0;

subject to SConstraint {j in P, t in T: t < ES[j]}:

Act[j,t]=0;

subject to continuityConstraint {j in P, t in T: t >= 2}:
t <= Fin[j]  ==>  Act[j,t] >= Act[j,t-1];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to enforce the logical implication
$$t \le \text{Fin}[j] \implies \text{Act}[j,t] \ge \text{Act}[j,t-1]$$
Equivalently, the contrapositive is
$$\text{Act}[j,t] < \text{Act}[j,t-1] \implies t > \text{Fin}[j]$$
Because Act is binary and Fin is integer, we can rewrite as
$$(\text{Act}[j,t] = 0 \land \text{Act}[j,t-1] = 1) \implies \text{Fin}[j] \le t-1$$
You can enforce this via a linear big-M constraint:
$$\text{Fin}[j] - (t-1) \le M_{j,t}(1 + \text{Act}[j,t] - \text{Act}[j,t-1])$$

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, what is actually the third line meaning? How is $\lt$ changed into $\land$? (It seems it is possible to use $\lt$ instead of $\leq$ when it comes to the logic form).

Comment: @A.Omidi For binary variables $x$ and $y$, the constraint $x<y$ has exactly one solution $x=0 \land y=1$.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, thanks. The logic is exactly what you mentioned. The interesting thing was of changing $\leq$ to $\lt$ and then using the logic form that is new to mine. 